# Validation failed for XSS vulnerable parameters having space charcter

Tags: vbscript, xss

I have VB script to check xss vulnerable parameters. It is executing and validating for parameters like "onmouseover=" but it is failing if there is a space character exist between "onmouseover" and "=" like "onmouseover =".I don't know removing space will be a optimum solution or not. Is there other way to do it please let me know.

```
Function XSSParameterChecker(str)
 if(InStr (str, "onmouseover(")) Then
   badCount = badCount + 1
End if

 if(InStr (str, "onmouseover=")) Then
   badCount = badCount + 1

 end if

 End function
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing all spaces from the string help me out. Adding below code resolve space charcters issue.

LCase(Replace(Replace(sParam," ",""),"&nbsp",""))